# python convention lstrip(s[, chars]). What does "[, chars]" signifies?

Tags: python, string

I'm a newbie in programming.
I was reading the Python documentation and could not understand the "s[, chars]" in [`lstrip(s[, chars])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip).

I'll appreciate if you can enlighten me.

Comment: The brackets indicate an optional argument.  It means you don't have to pass `chars`.

Comment: It means `chars` argument is optional.

Comment: Thanks. What does comma "," means?

Comment: You need a comma to separate arguments. For example: oneArgFunction(x) versus twoArgFunction(x, y)

Comment: Thanks guys! Got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chars` specifies the set of characters that should be stripped from the left end of the string.

The square brackets denote that the argument is optional. If not specified, there is a default set of characters to strip.

Examples:

- `lstrip('   abc ') == 'abc '`
- `lstrip('12345', '41') == '2345'`
- `lstrip('1112212345111', '12') == '345111'`

Note: This function `string.lstrip()` only exists in Python 2, not 3.